# How to make wowza streaming engine restream videos to facebook live?

Tags: wowza, facebook-live-api

I know there's a "stream targets" feature, but it allows me to configure Facebook target only for a particular FB user.

What I want is:

- my app will be used by many users with their own FB accounts
- when they live stream to my wowza streaming engine server it should re-stream to THEIR fb walls.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

At this time is it not possible to create Facebook Live stream targets using the REST API or with a Client-Side Application ... [read more](https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?50260-Facebook-Live-stream)

There a solution to transcode live/video (HLS/MP4) stream to RTMP (Facebook) using ffmpeg .

> Transcode HLS To RTMP (Facebook live)

```
ffmpeg -re -i "http://domain/x/x/input.m3u8" -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/111111111111111?ds=1&a=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

> Transcode MP4 To RTMP (Facebook live)

```
ffmpeg -re -i ./video.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame  -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/111111111111111?ds=1&a=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

[Facebook video format](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video-api)
**Video Format:**

- We accept video in maximum 720p (720 x 1280) resolution, at 30 frames
  per second. (or 1 key frame every 2 seconds)
- You must send an I-frame (keyframe) at least once every two seconds
  throughout the stream.
- Recommended max bit rate is 4 mbps.
- The Live API accepts H264 encoded video and AAC encoded audio only

**Audio Format:**

- Pixel Aspect Ratio: Square
- Frame Types: Progressive Scan
- Audio Sample Rate: 44.1 KHz
- Audio Bitrate: 128 Kbps stereo
- Bitrate Encoding: CBR

Create [Facebook live](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video-api) "Go Live Dialog"

call the following code to initialize a pop-up window with control that determine where to direct your POST request.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('liveButton').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'live_broadcast',
    phase: 'create',
}, function(response) {
    if (!response.id) {
      alert('dialog canceled');
      return;
    }
    //rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/111111111111111?ds=1&a=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    alert('stream url:' + response.stream_url);
    FB.ui({
      display: 'popup',
      method: 'live_broadcast',
      phase: 'publish',
      broadcast_data: response,
    }, function(response) {
    alert("video status: \n" + response.status);
    });
  });
};
</script>
```